# Error in asp.net webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

My asmx webservice is like this

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class GetRateRequestData : WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetParcelLookupData()
    {

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet, Formatting.Indented);

    }
}
```

And I am trying to access the data in browser like this

```
http://localhost:53569/services/GetRateRequestData.asmx/GetParcelLookupData/
```

But this throws an error like

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: GetParcelLookupData/ Web Service method name is not valid.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

I am new to webservices, Can any one point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: make your method public

Comment: @SainPradeep Sorry, It was public actually

Comment: still you are getting same error.

Comment: @SainPradeep Actually  It was public from the beginning , I just pasted the wrong code here. So yes, the error is same

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: @SainPradeep 4.5 , Actually I have updated my project from 3.5 to 4.5 some weeks back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65743/discussion-between-sain-pradeep-and-athul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decorate your method to allow HTTP GET requests

```
[WebMethod]  
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
public string MyMethod(int myint)
{
    // ... code here
}
```

and change your config as below

```
<system.web>
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
</protocols>
</webServices>
```

Comment: I think this is the solution too.